# Button not rendering correctly - LWJGL

Tags: lwjgl

Currently I am working on a game with LWJGL. I have started to implement a main menu screen although I have an issue.

Currently the button is just a Quad rendered as two triangles.
I know I am making a newbie mistake.

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to say the button is not showing anywhere.

Here is the relevant code:

Game:

```
if(state == GameState.MAIN_MENU){
            Graphics.doMainMenuGraphics();
}
```

Graphics:

```
public static void doMainMenuGraphics(){
    GL11.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 0);
    Setup.updateGraphics(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glEnd();

    menubutton.draw(); //Type is Button
}
```

Button:

```
//Only relevant code

@Override
public void draw() {
    if(hover){
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
        GL11.glColor3ub((byte) 0, (byte) 50, (byte) 205);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x-20, y-5);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x-20, y+5);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+20, y+5);

        GL11.glVertex2f(x-20, y-5);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+20, y-5);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+20, y+5);
        GL11.glEnd();
    }else{
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
        GL11.glColor3ub((byte) 150, (byte) 150, (byte) 155);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x-20, y-5);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x-20, y+5);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+20, y+5);

        GL11.glVertex2f(x-20, y-5);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+20, y-5);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+20, y+5);
        GL11.glEnd();
    }
    GL11.glColor3ub((byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 255);
}

@Override
public void update() {
    if(Mouse.getX() < x + 20 && Mouse.getX() > x - 20){
        if(Mouse.getY() < y + 5 && Mouse.getY() > y - 5){
            hover = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, Curlip.

Comment: Don't worry about GL11

Comment: To be more helpful, I think you mean import GL11 statically and then you don't have to type `GL11.` every time. And to OP, what is it doing or not doing?

Comment: The button wont show up

Comment: Java bytes are signed, so values like `(byte) 255` are causing overflow(not sure if that is what it is called). Generally everything above 127. Try something else, like int. But I am not really sure, maybe opengl java porters took care of that.

Comment: Using this method has work for everything else.

Comment: @curlip try the Color3f method and ensure that you're defining the vertices in the right order, they could be backface culled.

Comment: I have tried the Color3f method and there was no change.